# Number of subfolders in a folder directory

Tags: java, directory, subdirectory

I have a folder which consists of both datafiles (`.txt` etc) and subfolders.

In Java, how would I accomplish getting the number of subfolders in any specified directory path?

(so excluding the datafiles; only counting the subfolders)

I have read about counting the number of `.txt` files but can't seem to find anything about counting subfolders only.

I have no idea where to start but to give you an idea:

```
String directory = "C:\Users\ . \Desktop\ . \workspace\src\testfolder";
int numberOfSubfolders;

//what is numberOfSubfolders in testfolder?
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `FileFilter` to list only directories:

```
File file = new File("/tmp");
File[] files = file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        return f.isDirectory();
    }
});
System.out.println("Folders count: " + files.length);
```

Java `File` class is an example of the [Composite Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), so you have to actually ask the instance if it's a file: `isFile()` or if it's a directory `isDirectory()`.

If you want to count directories, and you're using Java 8. [`Files.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) function, can do the same thing in a more concise manner (practically one-liner):

```
long count = Files.find(
    Paths.get("/tmp"), 
    1,  // how deep do we want to descend
    (path, attributes) -> attributes.isDirectory()
).count() - 1; // '-1' because '/tmp' is also counted in
```

Comment: good answer. but is there a way to get actual maxDepth?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `File` class, you can list the files that are inside it (if it is a folder/directory) and you can filter by the property that you want (`isDirectory()`)

Then count the results.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
File dir = new File("yourDirPath");
int numberOfSubfolders;
File listDir[] = dir.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < listDir.length; i++) {
    if (listDir[i].isDirectory()) {
            numberOfSubfolders++;
        }
}
System.out.println("No of dir " + numberOfSubfolders);
```

Answer (score -1):

I just cringed so hard when I saw the for loop that has absolutely no use in the solution above. Just cut it out and do:

```
File dir = new File("yourDirPath");
File listDir[] = dir.listFiles();
int numberOfSubfolders = listDir.length;
```

This not only cuts the code in half, but the number of iterations is greatly reduced as you will run the for loop more as the number of directories increases. This only runs once.

Comment: Can you explain how this answer is different from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300105/number-of-subfolders-in-a-folder-directory/18300155#18300155)? Also does this code count the number of subfolders? It seems to count all files.