# scala, how to count folder in directory?

Tags: scala, directory

i have a problem about count the number of the folder in a specific directory with Scala.
i was searched on StackOverflow but just found how to count a file, not a folder.
thanks

Comment: You'd count the files that are directories (there is a flag for that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()).

Comment: If you want to use a Java API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300105/number-of-subfolders-in-a-folder-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way to do it:

```
def countOfSubDirectories(dir: String): Int = (
    new java.io.File(dir)).listFiles.filter(_.isDirectory).length
```

Comment: Why that `map(_.getName)` though ?

Comment: Isn't there `count(_.isDirectory)` that efficiently combines `filter().length` ?